# Como salvar uma função, com parâmetros pré-definidos, em uma variável em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Atualmente eu consigo salvar funções em variáveis da seguinte forma:

```py
def somar_iguais(lista, referencia):
  resultado = 0
  for x in lista:
    if lista[x] == referencia:
      resultado += referencia
  return resultado

SOMAR = somar_iguais

def main():
  numeros = [1,1,2,3]
  SOMAR(numeros, 1)
```

Eu quero salvar a função *somar_iguais* com o parametro *referencia* já definido, de modo que quando eu chamar a função pelo nome da variável eu precise fornecer apenas o parâmetro que ainda não está definido. Exemplo:

```py
def somar_iguais(lista, referencia):
  resultado = 0
  for x in lista:
    if lista[x] == referencia:
      resultado += referencia
  return resultado

SOMAR_UNS = somar_iguais(referencia: 1)
SOMAR_DOIS = somar_iguais(referencia: 2)

def main():
  numeros = [1,1,2,3]
  SOMAR_UNS(numeros)
  SOMAR_DOIS(numeros)
```

É possível fazer isso em Python 3.7.3? Como eu posso fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você consegue fazer isso através da função [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

somar_um = partial(somar_iguais, referencia=1)
somar_dois = partial(simar_iguais, referencia=2)
```

Assim, ao fazer `somar_um(numeros)` será o mesmo que fazer `somar_iguais(numeros, referencia=1)`.

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado :D

Comment: Encontrei uma outra solução: somar_um = lambda x: somar_iguais(x, 1)